# How to speed up GPU mode convolutional neural network with theano?

Tags: neural-network, gpu, theano, conv-neural-network

I'm using theano to implement a convolution neural network. My CPU RAM is 32G and GPU RAM is 2G, but the data is also very big -- almost 5G training data.

When the program is running, the computer seems to be frozen and each operation is really slow, even didn't respond. And the CPU mode seems to be at least 2x faster than GPU mode.

Is there any way to speed up the GPU convolutional neural network?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use Theano 0.7 with cudnn, this speed up convolution heavily:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/sandbox/cuda/dnn.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to use GPU accelleration first thing you need to install CUDA.
On the level of Theano configuration(Theano flags/TheanoRC) there are few ways you can speed-up your model with GPU:

1. Specify usage of GPU "device = gpu"
2. Enable Cuda memory allocation (CnMem) "cnmem = 0.75"
3. Enable CUDNN optimization "optimizer = cudnn"

You can read more about Theano config [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html#envvar-THEANO_FLAGS)